# Setting a background of Activity from Gallery in Android?

Tags: android, wallpaper

I'm trying to make a launcher for Android. And I'm right now working on setting wallpaper from `Gallery`. When I open `Gallery`, it works fine but when I choose image from `Gallery` my app **crashes**, any solutions? I modified code many time but no success.

Here's my code:

**MainActivity:**

```
public class Preferences extends Activity {

    String[] pref_list = { "Wallpaper" };
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private ImageView imageView;
    RelativeLayout wallpaper;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.preferences);

        RelativeLayout wallpaper = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_layout);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.lv_activity, pref_list);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pref_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                // currImageURI is the global variable I�m using to hold the
                // content:// URI of the image
                Uri currImageURI = data.getData();
                File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));

                if (file.exists()) {

                    Drawable d = Drawable
                            .createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    wallpaper.setBackground(d);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null,
                null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(idx);
        }
    }
}
```

**Logcat:**

> 05-22 13:13:37.232: D/OpenGLRenderer(6750): Flushing caches (mode 0)
>   05-22 13:13:38.474: D/OpenGLRenderer(6750): Flushing caches (mode 1)
>   05-22 13:13:38.591: V/KeyEvent(6750): Reset: android.view.KeyEvent$DispatcherState@41f1e658
>   05-22 13:13:39.021: D/OpenGLRenderer(6750): Flushing caches (mode 0)
>   05-22 13:13:43.294: D/dalvikvm(6750): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 454K, 12% free 15749K/17799K, paused 22ms
>   05-22 13:13:43.310: I/dalvikvm-heap(6750): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.236MB for 4915216-byte allocation
>   05-22 13:13:43.349: D/dalvikvm(6750): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 10% free 20537K/22663K, paused 27ms
>   05-22 13:13:43.365: W/CursorWrapperInner(6750): Cursor finalized without prior close()
>   05-22 13:13:43.419: D/dalvikvm(6750): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 10% free 20538K/22663K, paused 2ms+2ms
>   05-22 13:13:43.544: D/AndroidRuntime(6750): Shutting down VM
>   05-22 13:13:43.544: W/dalvikvm(6750): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e321f8)
>   05-22 13:13:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6750): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-22 13:13:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6750): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.RelativeLayout.setBackground
>   05-22 13:13:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at com.avoscent.sl.Preferences.onActivityResult(Preferences.java:76)
>   05-22 13:13:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4829)
>   05-22 13:13:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2996)
>   05-22 13:13:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3043)
>   05-22 13:13:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:129)
>   05-22 13:13:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1183)
>   05-22 13:13:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   05-22 13:13:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   05-22 13:13:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4516)
>   05-22 13:13:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-22 13:13:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   05-22 13:13:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   05-22 13:13:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   05-22 13:13:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6750):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   05-22 13:13:45.130: I/Process(6750): Sending signal. PID: 6750 SIG: 9

Comment: If your app crash then your Logcat damn sure telling you something..

Comment: Here's my some of logcat...

Answer (score 0):

```
 wallpaper.setBackground(d);
```

This method is available form API 16. if your working the below API level 16 it will causes  `NoSuchMethodException`